# reading specification sheet of a cable

Tags: cables, specifications, ffc

I'm having trouble reading the following specification sheet: https://www.molex.com/pdm_docs/ps/PS-15166-001-001.pdf

if it doesn't work, I just pressed the datasheet button in this product:
https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/molex/0151660158/3281039?s=N4IgTCBcDaIOoFkwFYAMA2AzAWgHIBEQBdAXyA

what exactly do "current rate 0.5 MIN" means? (page 4/5)
I thought it meant that the cable can't pass less than 0.5A, did I get it right?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

It means that its tested at those specs: they pass at least 0.5A on all conductors and the surface temperature of the cable cannot rise more than 10C above ambient(23C in that case). That alone doesn't mean that you can't pass more than 0.5A, it just means that if you pass more, its not guaranteed to meet that spec.

I did not see an absolute maximum current rating for the cable on the datasheet, however in practice you are more likely to be limited by other aspects (maximum temperature rating for the cable, maximum allowable voltage drop for your application, and perhaps more importantly, the maximum current rating of the connector you want to use).